# Vue.js and Vite Form Validation Not Executing Validator Functions Correctly

Tags: typescript, vue.js, testing, vuejs3, vitest

The following code comes from the official document of element plus, with several console. logs added

```js
// App.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { reactive, ref } from 'vue'
import type { FormInstance, FormRules } from 'element-plus'

const ruleFormRef = ref<FormInstance>()

const checkAge = (rule: any, value: any, callback: any) => {
  console.log('checkAge')

  if (!value) {
    return callback(new Error('Please input the age'))
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!Number.isInteger(value)) {
      callback(new Error('Please input digits'))
    } else {
      if (value < 18) {
        callback(new Error('Age must be greater than 18'))
      } else {
        callback()
      }
    }
  }, 1000)
}

const validatePass = (rule: any, value: any, callback: any) => {
  console.log('validatePass')

  if (value === '') {
    callback(new Error('Please input the password'))
  } else {
    if (ruleForm.checkPass !== '') {
      if (!ruleFormRef.value) return
      ruleFormRef.value.validateField('checkPass', () => null)
    }
    callback()
  }
}
const validatePass2 = (rule: any, value: any, callback: any) => {
  console.log('validatePass2')
  if (value === '') {
    callback(new Error('Please input the password again'))
  } else if (value !== ruleForm.pass) {
    callback(new Error("Two inputs don't match!"))
  } else {
    callback()
  }
}

const ruleForm = reactive({
  pass: '',
  checkPass: '',
  age: '',
})

const rules = reactive<FormRules<typeof ruleForm>>({
  pass: [{ validator: validatePass, trigger: 'blur' }],
  checkPass: [{ validator: validatePass2, trigger: 'blur' }],
  age: [{ validator: checkAge, trigger: 'blur' }],
})

const submitForm = (formEl: FormInstance | undefined) => {
  if (!formEl) return
  formEl?.validate((valid: any) => {
    console.log(valid)
    if (valid) {
      console.log('submit!')
    } else {
      console.log('error submit!')
      return false
    }
  })
}

const resetForm = (formEl: FormInstance | undefined) => {
  if (!formEl) return
  formEl.resetFields()
}
</script>
<template>
  <el-form
    ref="ruleFormRef"
    :model="ruleForm"
    status-icon
    :rules="rules"
    label-width="120px"
    class="demo-ruleForm"
  >
    <el-form-item label="Password" prop="pass">
      <el-input v-model="ruleForm.pass" type="password" autocomplete="off" />
    </el-form-item>
    <el-form-item label="Confirm" prop="checkPass">
      <el-input
        v-model="ruleForm.checkPass"
        type="password"
        autocomplete="off"
      />
    </el-form-item>
    <el-form-item label="Age" prop="age">
      <el-input v-model.number="ruleForm.age" />
    </el-form-item>
    <el-form-item>
      <el-button type="primary" @click="submitForm(ruleFormRef)"
        >Submit</el-button
      >
      <el-button @click="resetForm(ruleFormRef)">Reset</el-button>
    </el-form-item>
  </el-form>
</template>
```

The validation functions validatePass, validatePass2, and checkAge will all be executed in the browser and can be verified normally. However, with vitest, the validation functions will not be executed, and the value of valid is true

```
// App.spec.ts
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import About from '../src/About.vue'
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'

describe('About', () => {
  it('mount', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(About, {
      global: {
        plugins: [ElementPlus]
      }
    })
    await wrapper.find('.el-button').trigger('click')
  })
})
```